# Проецирование/работа c GUI win-приложением через web-браузер?

Tags: windows

Возникла необходимость иногда работать с приложением через браузер, т.е. запущенное на удаленной машине GUI-приложение должно проецировать исключительно свой (фокус) интерфейс в браузер (без окружения ОС) + управление (передача команд: мышь и клавиатура).

Есть хорошие инструменты типа TeamVewer, AnyDesk, RdWeb из пакета WS200x, но они не подходят по некоторым соображениям. Docker бы отлично подошел, но нет возможности рулить через WEB.

М.б. мне что то не известно из существующих программ. Подскажите, что есть еще.
Если готовых программ нет, какие библиотеки могут такое реализовать?

Comment: Может тебе нужен `headless` режим?

Comment: Что это за режим?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/oleg-bunin/blog/421137/